# FindRoot runs out of memory in Windows but not on Mac

Tags: memory

I am using `FindRoot` to find solutions to a large, highly oscillatory equation which I generated using other code.  When I run `FindRoot` in *Mathematica* 8 on my old macbook with OS 10.6, 1 GB Ram it takes maybe 2 hours to find a solution, but it can find a solution.  I tried to run `FindRoot` on the same equation in Mathematica 9 on a PC using Windows 7 with 6 GB Ram and the system runs out of memory giving an error

> No more memory available. Mathematica kernel has shut down. Try quitting other applications and then retry.

I am just running `FindRoot` so I cannot change the code, but I am wondering why I would run out of memory in Windows and not on my mac and how I could solve this problem in Windows?  Are there just settings I can change in *Mathematica* or Windows?

Comment: Is it possible to include the full code you are running?  It may make for a difficult problem to approach without it.

Comment: It might be due to Windows settings, that allows to use [certain part of memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You are comparing v8 on a mac with v9 on PC and you ask why the PC version causes a different behavior, right? Why are you so sure the difference isn't caused by a difference in versions?

Comment: I thought that it might be the different versions, but right now I only have version 9 on the PC, I will try to track down a version 8 I could run. The fact that I am just trying to run FindRoot (albeit on a complicated equation) makes me think that the Windows memory settings are the problem. I will look into this more.